# Is there a way to get substring with start and end position in perl?

Tags: string, perl

I know you can get a substring with `substr` but that's only with `start` position and `length` of substring. Is there another function that utilizes start and end position, or do I have to $length = $end-$start?

Answer (score 2):

If you use a negative index, it counts from the tail:

```
my $s = "The black cat climbed the green tree";
my $middle = substr $s, 4, -11;    #<-- "black cat climbed the"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the string as an array of characters:

```
join '', (split //, $string)[$start..$end]
```

But it’s probably nicer to use `substr` with `$end - $start`.

Answer (score -1):

In Perl to get sub-string use `unpack` function. Its faster then `substr` function.

**Example**:

> print unpack('A5','stackoverflow') ;
>
> print   unpack("x6 A6", 'stackoverflow');

**Output:**

> stack
>   verflo